# How to determine that user reached the end of a list in PowerApps Gallery control?

Tags: powerapps

I created a simple news browsing application with [PowerApps](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/). To display articles list I use [Gallery](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/control-gallery/) control named `NewsGallery`. The [data source](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/working-with-data-sources/) for it is a [collection](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/working-with-data-sources/#collections) of `Article` entities named `News`. What I want to do is dynamically [Collect](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/function-clear-collect-clearcollect/) more news to my `News` collection from my [custom api](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/register-custom-api/) when user scrolls down to the end of a Gallery control. **How can I handle such event? Is there some "undocumented" property like [Selected](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/control-gallery/#key-properties) to determine that user reached the end of a list?**

Answer (score 0):

There's a property in the gallery (which is not in [the documentation](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/control-gallery/)), `VisibleIndex`, which has the index of the item that is visible in the gallery.

Notice that usually your gallery will have multiple visible items, so it's possible that the VisibleIndex will never reach the number of elements in the gallery (`CountRows(<your collection>)`). In the example below, there are 20 elements in the Gallery1, but the visible index (shown in the text box below) shows 17, so you'll need to account for that when deciding the time to make a new API call to load more data.

[image: Gallery and VisibleIndex]

Notice that you can create an issue in the [PowerApps Ideas Board](https://aka.ms/powerapps-ideas) to suggest this feature (at least to make it easier) to the product team.